# Alternate row colours from 2nd row of the table using CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors

I have a table as below. I need to apply alternate colours starting from 2nd row. When I'm using nth-child selector to differentiate odd and even rows, the 1st row is being considered which isn't fulfilling the requirement.

So, how can we write a selector that ignores 1st row and starts applying colours from 2nd row considering 2nd row as odd row?

I know we can apply colour of odd row to even row and vice versa as a work around but some what it is confusing when we look at the code. So, I'm looking for an alternate solution for this table structure below. I appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>col 1</th>
      <th>col 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>32</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can used `nth-child()` css selector to chose odd and even. Then skip 2nd row by `nth-child(2)` selector.

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: green}
tr:nth-child(1) {
background:none;}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>col 1</th>
      <th>col 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>32</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>32</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>32</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Another way to achieve is separating `<thead>` and `<tbody>`.

```css
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {background: green}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col 1</th>
      <th>col 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>32</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In my scenario, we can't apply colour to the 1st row as we are not sure whether some where in the code the colour is already applied to it or not.

Comment: col1 and col2 not having color. you want same right ? you want to skip second which values 11 and 12 ? For differentiate you can add some border or none.

Comment: I want 2nd, 4th, 6th,... to be considered as odd rows and 3rd, 5th, 7th,... to be considered as even rows as we are ignoring the 1st row.

Comment: you first row means heading ? or row which having values 11 and 12 ? that is not cleared

Comment: Whether it is a heading or not it is still a table row. In this context it is a header row. Either ways we have to filter out first row and start our count from 2nd row as 1st row.

Comment: In this you can use solution because first row doesn't have background color. and virtually start from 2 row. then whichever color you want to give as per your odd row means (2,4,5) apply as even selector and vice versa.

Comment: yes, when someone go through the code this will misleads as we are applying even to odd and odd to even.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218413/discussion-between-aviboy2006-and-raj-kumar-boddu).

Comment: You can check second in my answer option to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [:nth-child() selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child). Also, if you are using `<th>` elements, you can put them in a [`<thead>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead).

```css
tbody tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background: peachpuff;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col 1</th>
      <th>col 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>42</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>52</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>62</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you don't want to alter your markup, you can start from the 3rd index.

```css
tr:nth-child(2n+3) {
  background: moccasin;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>col 1</th>
      <th>col 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>42</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>52</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>62</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is same as 2n selector and nothing specific to my scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `nth-child()` selector in combination with the `not()` selector.

```css
tr:nth-child(2n + 1):not(:nth-child(1)) {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: This will not just apply colour for 1st row and will apply colour to 3rd, 5th and so on. But, the 2nd, 4th, 6th and so on should be considered as odd rows in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you. Target first row separatly

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
tr:first-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>col 1</th>
      <th>col 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>31</td>
      <td>32</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In my scenario, we can't apply colour to the 1st row as we are not sure whether some where in the code the colour is already applied to it or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
 table > tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1) > td{
    background-color: #eee;
}
table > tbody > tr:first-child > td{
    background-color: #006c00;
}           
table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n + 2) > td{
    background-color: #d8e4bc;
}
```

Comment: In my scenario, we can't apply colour to the 1st row as we are not sure whether some where in the code the colour is already applied to it or not.

Comment: it will have none :) try it out
https://codepen.io/Codrey/pen/ZEQwZjN?editors=1100

Comment: 2n+1 is basically an odd row when we look at code but it is getting applied to the even row (2nd row if count starts from the actual 2nd row). So, I don't want to have this confusion between code and visual.